# Passing an Instance of a Service Through a Route in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm working with react router v4 in this case, which is important to note.

I have an App component, with an AuthService object successfully instantiated within it.

I'd like to get certain components that same Auth object instance, and those components are defined through a Route.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
const auth = new AuthService();

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/splash">Login</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} auth={auth}/>
        <Route exact path="/splash" component={SplashPage} auth={auth}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When Home or SplashPage renders, they have the typical props from Route, but no awareness of auth.

How can I get auth as one of the props, as well as those props coming from Route down to Home and SplashPage? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the route `render` function and pass the auth as prop to the components which require auth.

```
<Route {...routeConfig here} render={props => (
      <Home {...props} auth={auth}/>
)}/>
```

This way you can pass the custom props that your component needs.
Here's the [link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) to documentation.

Comment: What if I wanted to make an AuthRoute, such that I could use it to render any component that needs the auth instance? I have this much so far...

    const AuthRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
      return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
          return React.createElement(component, props);
        }}/>
      )
    }

Comment: Solved the last bit with this:

React.createElement(component, {...props, auth});

The sign of still being a rookie, the spread operator is still mysterious and amazing to me. : )

Comment: I had a similar situation back then. Render was not available for a route in react-router v2. The solution for me was to use a composed component. It help me wrap my components for additional behavior. It looked something like `<Route path="/profile" component={AuthWrapper(Profile)} />` Now the AuthWrapper was a simple wrapper component which rendered the Profile if auth met otherwise it took the user to the signin page. You can read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html)